# Acknowledge the proofreader of the thesis

Tags: thesis, acknowledgement

For the proofreading of my thesis I've used the help of a paid lector.
My question is, if it's normal practice to include this person into the acknowledgements of the thesis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I acknowledged my two volunteer proofreaders, but probably would not acknowledge a paid lector unless he went above and beyond what the fee covered.

In the case of acknowledgments, I think a safe rule is if you're not sure, put it in.  After all, you could type, "Thanks to Jane Doe for proofreading," faster than asking this question.

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy with the lectors work, you should also be happy to give him this reference.

The only thing in your thesis that will likely ever be read again are abstract and acknowledgements.

Comment: Oh...ouch!  That's gonna leave a nasty bruise! :)